# 3 div that do not fit 1 line

Tags: html, css

I want to split a row into 3 parts: 20%,60% and 20%. But for some reason, total width is more than 100% and last element is diplayes on new line. What is the problem?
I add margin 0 and padding 0 to all three. And 20% + 60% + 20% = 100%

CSS:

```
#text_area_row
    {
        position:relative;
        font-size:80px;
        width:auto;
        cursor:default;
        top:10%;
        margin: 0;
        padding:0;
    }
    #text_area_center
    {
        text-align:center;
        display:inline-block;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        width:60%;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    #center_div
    {
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    #text_area_left
    {
        text-align:left;
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        opacity:0.5;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        width:20%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    #text_area_right
    {
        position:relative;
        text-align:right;
        display:inline-block;
        opacity:0.5;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        width:20%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id='text_area_row'>
                <div id='text_area_left'>
                        <div class="card_style"></div>
                </div>
                <div id='text_area_center'>
                    <div id='center_div'>
                        <div class="card_style"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id='text_area_right'>
                        <div class="card_style"></div>
                </div>


            </div>
```

Comment: It looks like there is some space between text_area_left, text_area_right and text_area_center. But margin and padding are 0.

Comment: I found the solution - font-size:0; to parent div.

Comment: float:left; would work better (on the child divs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is whitespace, since you have made your `div` elements `display:inline-block`

You could compact your html by removing whitespace between those `div` tags..

```
<div id='text_area_left'>
    <div class="card_style"></div>
</div><div id='text_area_center'>
        <div id='center_div'>
            <div class="card_style"></div>
        </div>
</div><div id='text_area_right'>
        <div class="card_style"></div>
</div>
```

---

Another trick (*if you want to maintain the code formatting*) is to comment out the white space

```
<div id='text_area_left'>
        <div class="card_style">1</div>
</div><!--
--><div id='text_area_center'>
    <div id='center_div'>
        2
    </div>
</div><!--
--><div id='text_area_right'>
        <div class="card_style">3</div>
</div>
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/xYdWq/

Comment: This should be selected as an answer, the other answer is a workaround

Comment: I agree! I thought that if there is special symbol (&nbsp) then spaces are just ignored.

Comment: @Tigran `&nbsp;` forces a space and any character (*including space*) take up space, that gets added to your `div` widths and thus goes over 100%.

Answer (score 0):

use `float:left` for divs text_area_left,text_area_center,text_area_center
here your demo http://jsfiddle.net/N6fwu/